# Using password to write to Excel File using Epplus (C#)

Tags: c#, webforms, epplus

I am using Epplus to write to an Excel File in a web application.

The Excel file is password protected and is locked for editing (or doing anything else).
The issue arises as I am not required to use a password to write to Excel File.

**Is this normal behavior?**

Here is my code for accessing the protected file.

To open the existing worksheet I use this:

```
ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets["fileName"];
ws.Protection.IsProtected = false;        // No password required which concerns me
```

How I protect it before I close it:

```
ws.Protection.SetPassword("myPassword");
ws.Protection.IsProtected = true;
ws.Protection.AllowSelectUnlockedCells = false;
ws.Protection.AllowSelectLockedCells = false;
```

When I open the file the protection is there, I cannot make changes without using the password.

Do you guys have any ideas on what is going on?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "To Open existing worksheet". Does it meant the file is not password protected?

Comment: It is password protected, I want to unprotect it, update it then protect it after I am finished